# bidi and hyperref change hyphenation

Tags: hyperref, natbib, hyphenation, bidi

I try to compile th following document. If I load both `bidi` and `hyperref`, Mittelbach is not hyphenated. If I comment out one of them, everything is fine. The `bst`file is here: http://celxj.org/downloads/unified.bst

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unified} 

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{same}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{bidi}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
@book{GMS2013a,
        Address = {Boston},
        Author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michael Goossens},
        Edition = {2},
        Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
        Title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
        Year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Xx There is a huge amount of packages that can be used for various purposes. \citet{GMS2013a} is a good
reference book.

\bibliography{SM}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `natbib` doesn't have support for multiple languages; you may be luckier with `biblatex`.

Comment: I think it is not a `natbib` problem. The hyphenation works fine if `bidi` is not loaded. With `bidi` loaded not even explicit hyphenation with `\hypehenation{Mit-tel-bach}` is taken into account. If I use `\-`in the bibtex entry it works. If it was possible to extract the right to left typesetting from the `bidi` package, I would go for this. This would safe me the trouble with all the modified commands and side effects.

Comment: The `bidi` manual says in Section 2.3 that there are problems with `hyperref` if a link spans more than a line. I guess this is the reason for my problem as well.

Comment: Would you mind posting a rendering to illustrate why 'Mittelbach' should/should not be hyphenated?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2:** Peter Breitenlohner said:

> The solution is probably a modified definition of 'potentially
>   hyphenatable part' in `tex.web` ([40] Pre-hyphenation).

```
\hyphenation{first-word next-word last-word}
\showhyphens{start $ $firstword nextword nextword lastword$ $ end}
\bye
```

This does not seem to be bidi's problem but etex's problem. Try this (without using `bidi`):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unified} 

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urlstyle{same}


\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{bidi}

\TeXXeTstate=1

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
@book{GMS2013a,
        Address = {Boston},
        Author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michael Goossens},
        Edition = {2},
        Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
        Title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
        Year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Xx There is a huge amount of packages that can be used for various purposes. \beginL\citet{GMS2013a}\endL{} is a good
reference book.

\bibliography{SM}

\end{document}
```

Even a more minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\begin{document}
Xx There is a huge amount of packages that can be used for various purposes. \beginL Mittelbach \&  Goossens\endL{} is a good
reference book.
\end{document}
```

Also what you said in the comment about bidi manual and hyperref has nothing to do with this.

**UPDATE:** I have reported this issue to the author of e-tex; hopefully he has got a fix for this. Well, from my side, there is nothing to do except waiting for his reply.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in TeXLive sources. See [this commit](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/etexdir/etex.ch?r1=29312&r2=32197). So wait for texlive 2014 or build xetex from source.