# Minimal bidi for typesetting RL text

Tags: right-to-left, bidi

I need to typeset RTL text (Arabic, Persian) for linguistics books. I know of the `bidi` package. But `bidi`is way to powerful for our purposes and it has many side effects (it basically affects everything: title, footnotes, margin notes, ...). This results in problems with `hyperref` as described here: [bidi and hyperref change hyphenation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141769/bidi-and-hyperref-change-hyphenation)

What I need is just the support for using the script in the main text. So the question is: What do I need for this functionality? Can I use code from the `bidi` package? Could there be a package that users like me and `bidi`loads? This would be most modular, I guess ...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{bidi}

\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}

\begin{document}

Some Persian example: \PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**:

OK. I now have the following. This works nicely for one line, but breaks for longer text. The problem is that after a linebreak text should start at the right hand site and not in the middle of the page as if it was left to right text ending in the middle of the page.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}       

\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}

\newcommand{\TeXXeTOn}{\TeXXeTstate=1 }
\newcommand{\TeXXeTOff}{\TeXXeTstate=0 }
\TeXXeTOn

\newcommand{\RL}[1]{\beginR #1\endR}

\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}

\begin{document}

Some Persian example: \PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}


\PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت. و مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت. و مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت. و مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It depends on how much you want to achieve. You can easily switch to RTL using TeX--XeT (pdfTeX, XeTeX) or Omega-like primitives (LuaTeX), but a simple-minded approach will not necessary give you all the bells and whistles you need.

Comment: Could you please tell me how this is done? I looked at the manual and found `\beginR` and `\endR`, but `xelatex` complained: `! Improper \beginR.`

Comment: Minimal (plain) pdfTeX/XeTeX example: `\TeXXeTstate = 1
\newbox\mybox \everypar{\setbox\mybox\lastbox\beginR\box\mybox}` will make all paragraphs RTL and move the indent correctly.

Comment: Well, if it were Hebrew, I'd suggest the minimalistic [`cjhebrew`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cjhebrew) package. It doesn't look like there's an Arab equivalent though.

Comment: Loading `bidi` with no options means you want to typeset an LR document with some RL text. In LR mode, `bidi` does not change document behaviour (e.g. margins, footnotes, etc), but of course it gives you the ability to do so. Every change `bidi` does to internal macros of LaTeX and different packages, has a test to check whether you are typesetting in LR or RL mode. For LR, the macro will behave exactly as defined before loading `bidi`. You can also temporarily switch off TeX--XeT feature by `TeXXeTOff` (provude by `bidi`) and switch it back on by `TeXXetOn` in case you have a package clash.

Comment: And if you are using XePersian, of course it changes several options (footnote, margin, separators, counters, ...). So, for Persian scripts you can either borrow macros from `XePersian` or you can set your document as LR for default and use `\rl` for RL pieces of text and `persian` environment for persian paragraphs (which has different font and indention).

Comment: If you think `bidi` has many side effects or bugs, then please report them on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/vafa/bidi/issues), I will fix all of them and push a new release to CTAN. Well, I do not need to mention that if there is no official bug report (as outlined in `bidi` documentation), there is no way I could know about the bugs and fix them. Thus if you like to be helped, you need to help yourself first by reporting bugs. I hope that you do not expect me to check this site daily to see who has got problems and who does not? I am always available, but it is you that need to reach

Comment: @VafaKhalighi: How people are supposed to report bugs when you delete the repository/change it/change bug reporting address every other day?

Comment: @VafaKhalighi: Thanks for this hint. I did not know about the issue tracker but will use it in the future. I sent you an email in another issue to the address that was given in the manual. But this address seems to be dead. Anyway, one side effect is that you change the typesetting of the title which basically kills all modifications that have been done before. For the normal `bidi` user this is not a bug but for our purposes it is not nice. So this is not an issue for the issue tracker, I guess. I apologize for the claim about `hyperref` and `bidi` interaction in the other post.

Comment: @StefanMüller: You can always use `persian-tex@tug.org` address to email me and that never will be dead; in fact that is the current address in `bidi` documentation. Can you please give an example of the side effect that I change the typesetting of the title which basically kills all modifications that have been done before? if it is n `bidi` issue, I am happy to fix it. There is no need to apologise.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi:Thanks! This is what we try to do: https://github.com/langsci/latex We had a main class file (langsci.cls) and loaded the Komascript classes. In langsci.cls we redefined the title page and I was suprised to see that this did not work. I found out that this was due to loading `bidi`. We now found a way around the problem by delaying the redefinition of the title page. I asked for help here since these classes shall work for thousands of linguists. If it were just me there would not be a problem, since it works now. But I am afraid of side effects in other areas of the LaTeX world.

Answer (score 4):

You will be needing two different commands/environments to typeset Persian (or any other RTL language alongside Latin texts. One for small RTL texts along in an LTR paragraph, and one for RTL paragraph.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}       
\input{bidi.tex}
\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}
\newenvironment{PRTL}{\RTL\Parsifont}{\endRTL}

\begin{document}

Some Persian example: \PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}


\begin{PRTL}
او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت. و مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت. و مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت. و مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.
\end{PRTL}


\end{document}
```

`bidi.tex` is part of `bidi` package for bidirectional typesetting in plain XeTeX, so it is pretty much minimal. It redefines only a handful of commands, and they are essential for correct bidirectional typesetting.

[image: minimal bidi settings]